# Setting a select by option value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <div id="players" style="display:block">
    22
  </div>
  <select class="form-control playerDD" style="font-weight: normal" name="player_1" id="player_1">
    <option value="default">Select a player</option>
    <optgroup label="Available Players">
      <option value="22">John Smith</option>
      <option value="23">Jane Smith</option>
      <option value="24">Sam Smith</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Unavailable Players">
      <option value="25">John Smith 2</option>
      <option value="26">Jane Smith 2</option>
      <option value="27">Sam Smith 2</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var foo = $("#players").text();
    alert(foo);                       // Getting the right value and type
    //foo = "22";                     // This will work! 
    $("#player_1").val(foo);          // Does not work
    alert($('#player_1').val());      // Getting null
  </script>
</body>
```

**Problem:** I am trying to set the value of a drop-down list (id: player_1) based on the value in a div (id: players). I am able to read the value correctly but unable to set it. In the JavaScript, if I hard code the value of foo, it works!

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4w1ack9f/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#player_1').val(parseInt($('#players').text()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. I even wrapped with document.ready. Please see the jsfiddle.

Comment: got it - you need to convert the text to a number. in your fiddle - try var foo = parseInt($("#players").text())... this worked for me